# NLP logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data, logistic-regression

A basic doubt I have, Usually when dealing with text data for classic ML algos, We use Tf-idf which uses entire vocabulary for each row and assigns some weighted value.

My doubt is can I use 5 feature columns denoting the first 5 words to occur in the sentence and keep the target variable as some specific class.

Will this method work ? I am aware of RNN and LSTM, But was wondering if this would work ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a completely plausible model. You have five features (probably one-hot encoded) and then a categorical outcome. This is a reasonable place to use a (multinomial) logistic regression.

Depending on how important those first five words are, though, you might not achieve high performance. More complicated models from deep learning are able to capture more information from the sentences, including words past the fifth word (which your approach misses) and the order of words (which your approach does get, at least to some extent). For instance, compare these two sentences that contain the exact same words

`The blue suit has black buttons.`

`The black suit has blue buttons.`

Those have different meanings, yet your model would miss that fact.

Comment: I guess the question was understood wrong. I will clarify it…

Comment: So basically if I am using a vectorisation layer from keras. Each word of mine will have a unique integer assigned to it. Now, My question is, We usually feed this to our lstms for sequential processing. But what if I take these words and give it logistic regression. As an example :

Comment: @Iffu That seems to be the exact question that I answered.

Comment: If I have 2 sentence : 1.) My name is Alex 2.) Alex is my name Now my features are {[[1,2,3,4],[4,3,1,2]]}. Now if I feed this to my Logistic regression. will it work ?

Comment: As a concrete example, In logistic regression, The feature column order matters. Like first column is for the word “my” and so on. But in this model. Each column has a mixture of words with unique numbers. So will a logistic regression succeed in decoding this ?

Comment: It depends on the exact software implementation. Depending on how you code it, your software might figure out that the numbers refer to categories.

Comment: Thanks Dave, And one last doubt. How LSTM are able to figure out that a particular word has occurred. Like in classical algos, We have column order. But in LSTM, Since each cell receives different words, How does it know a particular word has occurred ?

Comment: Please post your new LSTM question as a separate question.